# Getting the interface of a Zope 3 browser layer knowing only it's name

Tags: plone, zope, zope3

Having a Plone skin interface registered as follow:

```
  <interface
      interface=".interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
      type="zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IBrowserSkinType"
      name="My Theme Name"
      />
```

What is the simplest way to get the interface (`my.app.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific`) knowing the name ("`My Theme Name`")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this:

```
>>> from zope.component import getUtility 
>>> from zope.publisher.interfaces.browser import IBrowserSkinType
>>> getUtility(IBrowserSkinType, name="Old Plone 3 Custom Theme")
<InterfaceClass plonetheme.classic.browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a buildout where this plone skin is installed, adding the `collective.recipe.omelette` to it will help you later being able to grep on all your packages for it.

So something like this will work:

```
grep -R --include=*.zcml 'My Theme Name' parts/omelette
```

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood my question, that was about getting the name from Plone/Python, in a dynamic way!